# Blurring an Image in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, blur

I have a 2D list of a grayscale image and a function that generates a n dimensional blur kernel. I'm completely stuck on how to make the kernel "run" on every pixel of the image calculating the averages (without using numpy or similar libraries). It's a homework so I'd prefer a hint on where to start rather than a complete code.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to do convolution over the image using the kernel. There are builtin methods in scipy that do this: https://scipy-lectures.org/intro/scipy/auto_examples/solutions/plot_image_blur.html

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/   you haven't done the most basic research befor posting this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)   it is all there. 1 google keyword away. come on.

Answer (score 0):

To tackle this problem from a programming problem-solving point of view -> you could consider this problem as a matrix (2D Array) multiplication problem. Where you pick a portion of your image pixels (2D Array) from the image and multiply it with the kernel matrix (also a 2D Array).

Say your image is 128x128 and kernel is 3x3, then you pick the first 3 rows and columns from the image and multiply with the 3x3 kernel, then slide to the next 3x3 portion in the image and multiply with the kernel again. You could do this until you reach the end of the image.

Another neat idea is to go through the source code of the libraries/functions (maybe numpy, scipy, or OpenCV) that could give us blurred images. I found this idea very useful during my assignments!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try to build a separate matrix multiplication function that will jump n cells each time.